# How to transform time form MySQL to JS, copare it and output to console

Tags: javascript, function, for-loop, time

I ran into a problem with a 'time' in JS. So basicaly I'm tring to get a time from databace as a string like `11:00` and `20:30`.

With the upcoming function code I convert it to js format:

```
function getDateFromHours(time) {
    time = time.split(':');
    let now = new Date();
    return new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate(), ...time);
}
```

After all I got this: `Mon Nov 09 2020 11:00:00 GMT+0300` and this: `Mon Nov 09 2020 20:30:00 GMT+0300`

So the first question:

1. How to compare these times to each other?
2. How to output every 15 minuties between these two times in concole to make it look like:
   `Mon Nov 09 2020 11:00:00 GMT+0300`
   `Mon Nov 09 2020 11:15:00 GMT+0300`
   `Mon Nov 09 2020 11:30:00 GMT+0300`

etc...

Answer (score 0):

For comparing times, and generating times algorithmically, you're best to work in timestamps. It's just a matter of converting between milliseconds and whatever unit of time you care to think in. You can get the timestamp from a Date object with the `getTime` method.

Comment: and how to get every 15 minities between these two times?

Comment: if you convert the first time into timestamps, then you just keep adding 15 minutes (converted to milliseconds, so 15 * 60 * 1000) to get the next one ... a simple for loop. You can convert back into a date with `new Date(timestamp)`